Tooltip of Slider in Ant Design show not correct
Tooltip of Slider in Ant Design show not correct
I have create Slide Component
    const SliderComponent = (props) => {
        const { 
            min = 0, max = 100, step = 1, initialValues = [0], onChange, isDisabled = false, range, isVertical = false, isIncluded = true, marks=[], minIcon, maxIcon, style
        } = props;
        const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValues);
        const handleChange = (newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
            if (onChange) {
                onChange(newValue);
            }
        };
        return (
            <div className={`${isVertical ? 'vertical-slider' : ''}`}>
                <Slider
                    min={min} 
                    max={max} 
                    step={step}
                    style={style}
                    value={value}
                    defaultValue={initialValues}
                    vertical={isVertical}
                    included={isIncluded}
                    disabled={isDisabled}
                    range={range ?? false}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    marks={markData}
                />
            </div>
            
        );
    };

and when i render slider, the tooltip show in the bottom and cannot use css, just show the value


Please help me
